# How does ButtonListener() work when it is both a parent and a child class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, actionlistener

I have a culminating project for school where I have to include as many elements I have learnt this semester and 2 of them are methods and gui. In the program that I'm trying to make, there is both a ButtonListener in a parent and a child class but there is an error in the parent class on the line:`nameConfirm.addActionListener(new ButtonListener())` which says that ButtonListener cannot be resolved to a type. I know this has something to do with hierarchy but I can't figure out how I should fix it.

I have a vague idea that some people use "this" or override but I don't really understand how those work.

This is the parent class:

```
public void startGame() {
    JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
    JButton nameConfirm = new JButton("ask");
    nameConfirm.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    namePanel.add(nameConfirm);
    setContentPane(namePanel);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 175);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    }
}
```

and this is the child class:

```
public cpt2() {
    JPanel startingPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    newGame.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    buttonPanel.add(newGame);
    checkStats = new JButton("Statistics");
    checkStats.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    buttonPanel.add(checkStats);
    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    buttonPanel.add(exit);
    startingPanel.add(buttonPanel);
    setContentPane(startingPanel);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1110, 375);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
public class ButtonListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() == newGame){
            cptRun.startGame(); 

        }
        else if (a.getSource() == checkStats){

        }
        else if (a.getSource() == exit){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I hope to get rid of the error and have working buttons for the different JPanels in both the parent and the child class.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: nameConfirm.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

Comment: Here is a link to Oracle's Java tutorials topic on [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). You may also want to search the net (Google) with similar queries to find more examples.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the parent class

That is a **method**, and you have in-lined a `class` within a method.

The more common way to do that would be

```
nameConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    // Implement ActionListener methods here, within anonymous class
});
```

Or move the anonymous class to a variable

```
final ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
    // Implement ActionListener methods here, within anonymous class
};
nameConfirm.addActionListener(buttonListener);
```

> and this is the child class

It's not clear which is the class here. You have a constructor `cpt2` and `public class ButtonListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener`

I think what you wanted instead was this, for example

```
public class Cpt2Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public Cpt2Frame() {
        // some button
        someButton.addActionListener(Cpt2Frame.this); // 'this' class 'is-a' ActionListener
    }

    // Implement ActionListener methods within defined class
}
```

Or you could create a *separate file* `ButtonListener.java`, which should not be a JFrame, only a listener interface

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

}
```

Then, you could do `addActionListener(new ButtonListener())`

Comment: So, what you're referring to is that whatever action I want done with the button, I put it in `{}` while initializing the action listener in the parent class? Also, I realized I mixed up one of the brackets when I was trying to trim the code down to what's necessary. Would it be possible to look over the child class again?

Comment: I don't think your problem is with patent/child classes. There is only one way to add an action listener to a button. You just shouldn't start a line within a method with `class`, and there can only be one top level `public class` per Java file